# Loading content from ajax request into dom node in DOJO

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm wondering is there a quick way in DOJO to load ouput of http request into some
DOM node like in jQuery

```
$('#injectMe').load('/someResource', {
    id: 223,
    xxx: "2323"
});
```

ps I know about dojo.xhr* methods :) Maybe there is a simpler method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ContentPane` with a url to specify the content.

```
<div id="foo" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" href="/some/page.html">
</div>
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html

Comment: How to get the response of this content pane ajax request through href can be received in javascript on domready of "/some/page.html" page? Is it possible?